# SQL - count the number of occurrences in all columns

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to create some validation routines for an analytics system.

We have large tables with data.  If a particular calculation all or most of a column might be zero.  In practice values aren't usually exactly 0, so many occurrences of 0 indicates a potential issue. I want to write a single query that counts the number of 0's in each columnn.  For instance, if my data was:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 23 | 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 0 | 54 | 3 | -2 |
| 3 | 3 | 45 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 32 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 |

I would like to get a count of the number of occurrences of 0 in each column.  The result for the table above would be: (0,4,1,2,0)

Is there a good way to do this in SQL for tables with an arbitrary number of columns?

Obviously I can't do:

```
select count(col1), count(col2), count(col3), count(col4), count(col5)
from table 
where col1 = 0 and col2 = 0 and col3 = 0 and col4 = 0 and col5=0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_col1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col2 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_col2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col3 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_col3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col4 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_col4,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col5 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_col5
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that on databases which support summing boolean expressions, the above might be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(col1 = 0) AS cnt_col1,
    SUM(col2 = 0) AS cnt_col2,
    SUM(col3 = 0) AS cnt_col3,
    SUM(col4 = 0) AS cnt_col4,
    SUM(col5 = 0) AS cnt_col5
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using SQLite, and the second one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `WHERE` condition and conditional aggregation to filter the row before aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS col1_0_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col2 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS col2_0_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col3 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS col3_0_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col4 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS col4_0_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col5 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS col5_0_count
  FROM yourTable t
 WHERE 0 IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(case when col1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) col1_0,
SUM(case when col2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) col2_0,
SUM(case when col3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) col3_0,
SUM(case when col4 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) col4_0
FROM yourTable;
```